# iText 7 : xref subsection not found

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to open [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-lxMBRpuh5Nz2VCmeiTcsZDRS0thgYQ/view?usp=sharing) and I get the following error:

```
12:30:26.431 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader - Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 132.
    at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.throwError(PdfTokenizer.java:640)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXrefSection(PdfReader.java:793)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:766)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:537)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1796)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:238)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:221)
    at com.example.ITEXTTests.test(ITEXTTests.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: xref subsection not found.
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

It's a very simple PDF created with Acrobat DC. It only contains one text field. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please could you tell what exactly version of iText you use to open the pdf?
I've tried to do it with the most recent one (7.1.5) and everything is OK.

Comment: There is no version 7.1.5. Last version I see is 7.1.4 and this is the version I use.

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk Could you please post the code you use to open the PDF? (I'm probably doing something wrong)

Comment: Sorry - this was due to Maven resources filtering. Fixed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MickaelMarrache, could you please share the details of what caused the problem and how you fixed it? We would then have an answer!